# Chamar classe que gera JSON

Tags: php, json, classes

Bom dia! Estou quebrando a cabeça para recuperar a Classe que gera o JSON, tenho a seguinte classe nome de apiBusca.php

```
 public function enviarRequisicao() {                
    $url = 'API';

    $json = new StdClass();
    $json->Chave = $this->Chave;
    $json->Senha = $this->Senha;
    $json->TipoViagem = $this->TipoViagem;
    $json->Companhias = $this->Companhias;
    $json->Adultos = $this->Adultos;
    $json->Criancas = $this->Criancas;
    $json->Bebes = $this->Bebes;
    $json->Trechos = $this->Trechos;
    $data = json_encode($json);                

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

No arquivo api.php de exibição dos dados coloco da seguinte forma:

```
$chave = "MINHA_CHAVE";
$senha = "MINHA_SENHA";
$tipoviagem = 1;
$companhias = array("GOL");
$adultos = 1;
$criancas = 0;
$bebes = 0;
$trechos = array(array("Origem" => "$Origem", "Destino" => "$LugarDestino", "DataIda" => "$DataIda", "DataVolta" => "$dataVolta"));
$objeto = new apibuscamilhas($chave, $senha, $tipoviagem, $companhias, $adultos, $criancas, $bebes, $trechos);
$ida = new apibuscamilhas();
$ida->Chave = "MINHA_CHAVE";
$ida->Senha = "MINHA_SENHA";
$ida->TipoViagem = 0;
$ida->Companhias = array("GOL");
$ida->Adultos = 1;
$ida->Criancas = 0;
$ida->Bebes = 0;
$ida->Trechos = array(array("Origem" => "$Origem", "Destino" => "$LugarDestino", "DataIda" => "$DataIda"));
```

Dúvida não consigo exibir ela a não ser através do var_dump($ida->enviarRequisicao());

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obrigado

Comment: Utilize `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` como `true` para retornar os dados e dê um `echo json_encode($ida);` no `api.php`

Comment: Adicionei o CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ficando assim curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $data); e no arquivo api.php ele me retornou apenas {}

Comment: Adicionou o `echo json_encode....` também? O arquivo `api.php` tem que imprimir um valor para então, o arquivo `apiBusca.php` recuperar.

Comment: Sim adicionei e não me retornou!